# Counting images and updating counter based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a column of images that I would like to add a counter to show which one is the main one at the moment, based on a scroll position.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cenbpxm3/)

```
<div class="counter">1/7<br>(the number before the "/" needs to be dynamic, I can get the total)</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
</div>

.counter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see the scroll position. can you add a class for the main image ?

Comment: @Mahmoud The main image should be the one that is showing the most in the viewport.

Comment: I just added a simple code as a solution, hoping that I understood your request

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are trying to update the variable X in `X / 7` indicating which images is currently visible.  Given your current HTML, try this:

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function(excludePartials) {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  
  if (excludePartials) {
    var bottomVisible = (elementBottom - viewportTop) / $(this).outerHeight();
    var isInView = elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    
    return isInView && bottomVisible > 0.5; // false if its less than 50% visible
  }

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  // new array to store all images in view
  var imagesInView = new Array();
  $('.image').each(function() {    
    // pass in false if partially visible objects should be used
    if ($(this).isInViewport(true)) {       
      var i = $(".image").index( $(this) );
      imagesInView.push(i);
    }
    // get the earliest viewable image:
    $("#active").text( imagesInView[0] + 1 ); 
  });
});
```

```css
.counter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter"><span id='active'>1</span>/7<br>(the number before the "/" needs to be dynamic, I can get the total)</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
</div>
```

You can play with the tolerance or disable partially visible elements by reading the comments and adjusting the variables accordingly.

I found the `isInViewport` snippet here: https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2